# Correctly placing a call to a display function in recursion (Hanoi towers)

Tags: c, recursion

I'm faced with the task of coding a function (in C) that solves the Hanoi towers problems and displays every move of a disk.
The recursive function in question is: `void hanoi(int m, int *I, int* J, int* K)`, where m is the number of disks to move from the array I to K, using the intermediary array J.
Now, I coded this function successfully (I think) but can't place the printing function so that the system is displayed after each move of a disk.

```
void hanoi(int m, int* I, int* J, int* K) {
    if(m>0) {
        hanoi(m-1, I, K, J);
        deplacer(I, K);
        hanoi(m-1, J, I, K);
    }
}
```

The function `void deplacer(int *A, int* B)` moves the top disk from A to B (supposing it's legal).
The function `void dessine(int* I, int* J, int* K, int m)` draws the system (in console) as it is.
In a nutshell: I can't properly place the call (or calls ?) to 'dessine' inside of the body of 'hanoi' so that the system is displayed in the order of execution.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that is changing the state of your towers is the function `deplacer()`. So if you want to visualize how the state changes over time, you should call `dessine()` right after you call `deplacer()`.